# google analytics no configuration

Tags: drupal

I am using Drupal 7. I have installed google analytics module for my website traffic.
Here is the steps that I made.
1. I downloaded https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics
2. Log in into my website as admin Modules->Installed new Modules
3. Check google analytics checkbox-> save configuation.

after I did the 3 steps, I found the permission and Configurayion beside Google analytic. But when I click configuration. the output is this.

https://www.diigo.com/item/p/qeoacqozbrraosecozbbsrcsod/4869c24609380fb6fe4369e77e657db4

I can't see the configuration where I will put the javascript from my google analytic account.

Need some help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clear your cache after enable Google Analytics module, you should able to see Configuration setting.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much this is a big help.. thank you :)

Comment: Actually you don't have to put tracking code. all you need to do is put your Google Analytics correspond domain WEB PROPERTY ID start with UA-*****. That's it!

Comment: thank you so much. But how can I see the visitors of the page? I can't see the visitors for today.

Comment: actually after 24 hour, you can see the visitor. And also you can see Real Time report. play around google analytics bit.